# Printing multiple rows from array with same search criteria

Tags: c#, arrays

I am doing an application where I give the ID of a flight and the program prints the info of all the passengers on that flight. I managed to do it so that I can search a passenger with his ID and print the info of the flight he is on, but I can't do it other way round. Any tips? These are the arrays:

```
    Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[] {
            new Passenger("John", 100, 200),
            new Passenger("Mark", 101, 200),
            new Passenger("Charlie", 102, 201)};

    Flight[] flights = new Flight[] {
            new Flight(200, "Berlin", "Moscow", "05.10.2016"),
            new Flight(201, "Paris", "Madrid", "06.10.2016")};
```

Passenger and Flight have the same ID so I use that to link the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2023861 beat me to it but here is a more complete example using a where clause to filter the results on flight ID
Complete code here: https://github.com/drGarbinsky/PrintFlightsExample

```
   var data = from f in flights
                   join p in passengers on f.ID equals p.Flight
                   where f.ID == searchId
                   select new { flight = f, passenger = p };

        if (data.Any())
        {
            var format = "{0} departs {1} for {2} on flight {3} in seat {4} on {5}";
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, item.passenger.Name, item.flight.Origin, item.flight.Destination,item.flight.ID, item.passenger.Seat, item.flight.Date));
            }
        }
```

The output looks like:

```
John departs Berlin for Moscow on flight 200 in seat 100 on 05.10.2016
Mark departs Berlin for Moscow on flight 200 in seat 101 on 05.10.2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join together your arrays by flight id like this:

```
var joined = from p in passengers
             join f in flights on p.FlightId equals f.FlightId
             select new { p, f };
```

And then you can loop through like this:

```
foreach(var match in joined) {
    Console.WriteLine("Passenger name = " + match.p.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Flight time = " + match.f.FlightTime);
}
```